# Using React to call a variable from multiple files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is arranged like so:

**main.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Console = require('./console.jsx');
var Dashboard = require('./dashboard.jsx');

var datastored = new Dexie('Notes');
datastored.version(1).stores({entries:'++id, title, entry' });
datastored.open().catch(function(err){alert("Could not open database:"+err)});
```

This `main.jsx` boots up my database via the `datastored` variable, which uses the IndexDB wrapper [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org/). Now, I would like to call the `datastored` variable from my other files (such as `console.jsx` or `dashboard.jsx`).

In my particular instance, I have a `<Addnote/>` inside `<Dashboard/>`. Inside `<Addnote/>` I have this function.

**addnote.jsx**

```
sendthru:function(){
     var newInput = {
     title: this.inputTitle.value,
     entry: this.inputEntry.value    
     }; 
     datastored.entries.add(newInput).then(()=>this.runcheck());
     this.inputTitle.value = '';
     this.inputEntry.value = '';    
},
```

When `sendthru` is launched, however, my console error states that `datastored is not defined`. So I'm wondering how I would enable my entire app to make calls to the `datastored` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your data in another module. Modules are singletons, so you could create your own file (say, `storage.js`) and inside of it export an object with fields you would like to make available to the rest of your code. Then when you `require('./storage')` you will have access to that same data everywhere else.

Comment: So I assume on `main.jsx` that would look like `var datastored = require('./storage.js')`? And then on storage.js that would look like `module.exports= new Dexie('Notes');`?

Comment: Sure you could start like that and change it if you find you need more data